# Vuetify - how to make sticky elements?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm new to Vuetify (first project ever) and I'm trying to set a card inside a column sticky top. Unfortunately is not working as supposed. I've also tried using the v-scroll directive from vue-sticky-directive and the result is still the same.

Here the simplified snippet:

```
<v-row>
   <v-col class="sticky-container">
     <v-card class="sticky-card">This should be sticky top 90px</v-card>
   </v-col>
   <v-col>
     content
   </v-col>
</v-row>

.sticky-container{
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sticky-card{
  position: sticky;
  top:90px;
  align-self: start;
}
```

I know I can achieve a similar result using position:fixed, but the behavior is different and the final result is not the one I'm looking for.

Did someone already faced this issue and have a some insights to share with me?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me(pug syntax):

```
v-row(no-gutters)
  v-col(sm='0' md='0' lg='1')
    div(position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 100px')
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you need to set `position` to `fixed`. As fixed is a kind of absolute positioning you can than set the top position via `top: 90px` -
and with fixed positioning you'll loose all fluid features of that card as well as the centering. For instance `max-width` won't work so you have to use `width` instead and center by yourself.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row>
     <v-col cols="12">
       <v-card 
         class="mx-auto sticky-card"
         max-width="344"
         color="primary"
         >
         <v-card-text>
           <b>This should be sticky top 90px</b>
         </v-card-text>
       </v-card>
     </v-col>
     <v-col>
        <v-card 
         class="mx-auto after-sticky"
         max-width="344"
         >
         <v-card-text>
           Card with much content - past large text inside of it         
         </v-card-text>
       </v-card>
     </v-col>
  </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sticky-card {
  width: 344px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* centering */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
}

.after-sticky {
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Doesnt look 'sticky', looks very much 'fixed' - the point is to stay in viewport when scrolling past, not stay in one place for all eternity.

Comment: Fixed != Sticky. While it may remain in place as you scroll, it won't stop at the bounding box